# How to properly call recursively a function on img onerror callback?

Tags: javascript

I'm triying to set an image src by constructing its path and filename.

This is my code:

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=0;
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var testImages= function() {
    img.src = "Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
    i++;
    if (i<extensions.length)
        img.onerror = testImages;
}

testImages();
```

But I don't know what is happening. If I do:

```
img.onerror = testImages;
```

it seems like only the last extension is proccesed because I get:

```
GET file:///home/beol/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.GIF net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

If I do:

```
img.onerror = testImages();
```

the function is called recursively infinite times.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with y code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this - you do need to assign the handlers before setting the src:

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=1;
var img = document.querySelector("img");
img.onerror = function() {
    console.log("error:"+this.src);
    if (i<extensions.length) img.src="Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
    i++;
}
img.onload=function() {
    console.log("success:"+this.src);
}
img.src="Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[0];
```

If you have more than one image with different extension and you want to test both loads and errors it could look like

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/deLm7p7e/)

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=0;
var img = document.querySelector("img");

function loadnext(img) {
  if (i<extensions.length) {
    img.src="Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
    i++;
  }
}
img.onerror = function() {
    console.log("error:"+this.src);
    loadnext(this);
}
img.onload=function() {
    console.log("success:"+this.src);
    loadnext(this);
}
loadnext(img);
```

and if you do not care to handle the errors or loads specifically, you can do this

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=0;
var img = document.querySelector("img");
function loadnext() {
  if (i<extensions.length) {
    this.src="Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
    i++;
  }
}
img.onload=img.onerror=loadnext; // no ()
img.onload(); // start
```

Comment: I think OP means the opposite: try another extension if load has failed, not if it has loaded properly.

Comment: the #1 issue is he assigns the error handler in the loop after setting the src

Comment: Why is that an issue? You mean the handler ha so be set before setting the src because the image presumably is getting loaded immediately?

Comment: Because it will not execute since the error was already hit. It will trigger the next time though. Yes, as I pointed out in my answer. Always assign handlers before triggering them

Comment: thanks mplungjan, I tried this but now I get:
GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and 
GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.GIF net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
so it seems that only the first and last item of the array are processed.

Comment: I tried the code  mplungjan but I get the same error: GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.GIF net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: thanks man, I don't know what the code works in jsfiddle. That is the reason I din't add a jsfiddle to the question. In jsfiddle, all items of the array are processed. But outside jsfiddle, with my browser Chromium Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), it seems like only the first item and the last one are processed.

Comment: Weird - I cannot help there

Comment: I don't know what is happening but since you were the first one to answer the question, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend this change:

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=0;
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var testImages= function() {
    if (i<extensions.length) {
        img.src = "Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
        i++;
    }
}
img.onerror = testImages;
testImages();
```

Your code as written was updating the `img.src` even after the extensions array had been consumed. This caused the `img.onerror` event to trigger again due to setting the src to "Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.undefined"

Comment: thanks man, but know I get:
GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and 
GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.GIF net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
so it seems that only the first and last item of the array are processed.

Comment: What browser could you possibly be using? [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e6Lz7m8t/) errors on all extensions, as seen in my console.

Comment: thanks again, I didn't add a jsfiddle to the question because the code works well in jsfiddle, and all items of the array were processed. I don't know why it works in the jsfiddle. My browser is: Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

```
var extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "JPG","JPEG","png","PNG", "gif", "GIF"];
var i=0;
var img = document.querySelector("img");
var testImages= function() {
    img.src = "Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa."+extensions[i];
    i++;
    if (i>=extensions.length)
        img.onerror = null;
}
img.onerror = testImages;
testImages();
```

This works for me.

Comment: thanks man, as the other answers, I get: GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND and GET file:///home/lucas/Desktop/Wildschwein_Sus_scrofa.GIF net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND so it seems that only the first and last item of the array are processed

Comment: but i can see ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND for all eight extensions. Would you care to check again?

Clearing your caches might help.

Comment: I checked again in Chrome and Chromium but I only get the error for the first and last item.